# Sprite Kit doesn't work anymore with iOS 9

Tags: ios, sprite

I was testing my app with iOS 8 and it was working fine on iPhone 4s and 
iPad mini 3. Then, I updated my devices and Xcode and now my app
isn't working anymore.

Loading time iOS 8 : 1-3 seconds.
Loading time iOS 9 : 3 minutes and more to load nothing ( it freezes ).

I tried to comment the method where I preload texture atlases and my scene,
but nothing. It doesn't load (it is stuck on the launch screen).

I was releasing an update and now I don't know what to do sincerely.

Does anyone have any tip?

Comment: on the simulator or are you running on your device?

Comment: Both simulator and device are not working.

Comment: hmmm.  the only issue I seemed to have was SpriteNodes that I didn't specifically set the zPosition showing up behind my background images.  Youve tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Tried everything. If i comment the method that loads SpriteKit ( scene ), the app doesn't run, if i comment the code not related to SpriteKit ( NSUser,AVAudio,UIButton,UIView ) my app doesn't run , if i add "return" after "[super viewDidLoad]" the app obviously shows grey in 1 sec, but: 1 more line of code and nothing runs